# When to use potentials in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is it grammatically correct to use *potentials* in the following sentence:

> Software tools analyze data and report potentials issues.

Comment: In this case, *potential* is an adjective and should not have an *s* at the end.

Comment: Do you mean that they report issues about potentials (perhaps voltage differences?), or that they report things that may potentially be or become issues?

Comment: In English, adjectives are not used in plural like in Spanish. Lose the "s"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using it in [one of its noun senses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potential#Noun) and it is plural:

> All of the batteries have different potentials.

(This would also be the case if you were using it in a verb sense used in third person singular, but *potential* doesn't usually get used as a verb).

Adjectives in English do not, unlike some other languages, change to agree with the noun they are modifying, so we would use *potential* rather than *potentials* with both plural and singular cases. So in any of [its adjective senses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potential#Adjective) we use *potential*:

> Software tools analyse data and report **potential** issues.
>
> Each **potential** issue should be investigated.

Comment: Just to add to this, if it is the noun sense, you could say *"Software tools analyze data and report issues with voltage potentials."*.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing for many, even if you mean the issues about the potentials.

Either clarify yourself with:

"Software tools analyse data and report **potential** issues."

or:

"Software tools analyse data and report issues with any **potentials**."